# Detecting a change on a webpage under Gateway z/OS?

Tags: web, zos, rexx, ispf

When developing a web application under Gateway z/OS I have been using two different techniques to detect when the user enters, or changes, data on the webpage.

1. I have a hidden variable for the fields so that I can compare the displayed field value to the hidden value.  Pros: everything is there when the user submits the page to compare. Cons: the page is larger.
2. I save the variables for each field in the session variable pool to compare. Pros: keeps the page smaller. Cons: can fill up the session pool if not managed.

Note that I'm enabling an ISPF dialog written in REXX to run under the web.

Both work well but is there a better way?

For pages where there are few fields/variables this either is good. For pages with tables there could be 100's of fields/variables.

Thanks for any tips.